# How to calculate Sum of Squares of a list in python?

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I have a list like this;

```
A = [111,222,333,444]
```

I want to calculate the Sum of Squares of this list using python

so far I tried this;

```
value = ((sum([i**2 for i in A]))-(sum(A)**2)/len(A))
```

but I am not sure if this is correct. Is there a way to do this in numpy?

Comment: so, your formula returns the difference between the sum of squares and the average square of list elements

Comment: Looks like you actually want to calculate the variance. The sum of squares is just covered in your initial term, `sum(i**2 for i in A)` (no need to make a list, `sum` will take a generator).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compute the sum of squares of a list with numpy:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([111, 222, 333, 444])
>>> np.sum(A**2)
369630
```

This is equivalent to the expression `sum([i**2 for i in A])` in your code.

It looks like you have some additional operations after that. I'm not exactly sure what quantity you're trying to compute, but there are idiomatic ways to compute things like variance, MSE, etc. in numpy as well.